# Binding an ImageSource to the second level of MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, prism

The following ViewModel code loads an image and then sets it as the `AppBackground` property:

```
public class ShellViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        var Stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetManifestResourceStream("Application.Resources.Images.Background.jpg");
        var bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.StreamSource = Stream;
        bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bi.EndInit();
        AppBackground = bi;
    }

    public ImageSource AppBackground
    {
        get { return _AppBackground; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _AppBackground, value); }
    }
    ImageSource _AppBackground;
}
```

And just by adding this command, the image is displayed correctly:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding AppBackground}" />
    </Grid.Background>
    ...
</Grid>
```

## The Problem

Now, I want to encapsulate the image inside a class, like `Settings` for example, and I pass it through the interface`ISettings` to then export it with MEF and import it into the viewmodel:

```
public class ShellViewModel : BindableBase
{
    [Import]
    public ISettings Settings
    {
        get { return _Settings; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Settings, value); }
    }
    ISettings _Settings;
}
```

The image load is done within the `Settings` class:

```
public class Settings : BindableBase, ISettings
{
    public Settings()
    {
        var Stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetManifestResourceStream("Application.Resources.Images.Background.jpg");
        var bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.StreamSource = Stream;
        bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bi.EndInit();
        AppBackground = bi;
    }

    public ImageSource AppBackground
    {
        get { return _AppBackground; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _AppBackground, value); }
    }
    ImageSource _AppBackground;
}
```

The definition of the `ISettings` interface is:

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(ISettings))]
public interface ISettings
{
    ImageSource AppBackground { set; get; }
}
```

And finally, by changing the xaml code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Settings.AppBackground}" />
    </Grid.Background>
    ...
</Grid>
```

The image is not displayed.

## What I have already tried

- I checked that the export-import was done correctly, using the debugger.
- I checked that the image was loaded correctly, using the debugger.
- I verified that the binding was done correctly, checking the returned message:

> System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage

When I add the following code in the same view:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Settings.AppBackground}" />
```

- I changed the property type to another (like double or string) and the `{Binding Settings.AppBackground}` path worked as it should.

## What I suspect

- I am ignoring basic binding issues.
- I am ignoring some issues with binding to the ImageSource type.
- I just found a bug in the WPF binding system.

I hope it's not really the last.

## So, my questions

1. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?
2. What other solution could solve this MVVM scenario?

Comment: Any reason why you load the images that way? In WPF, you would usually set the Build Action of the image files to `Resource` and load them by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx), like `new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Background.jpg"))`.

Comment: By saying that you "changed the property type to another (like double or string) and the {Binding Settings.AppBackground} path worked as it should", you already found out yourself that you did not find a bug in the framework. Quite certainly the image resource just wasn't found. If class Settings is in a different assembly, use a Pack URI with Referenced Assembly, like `pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Images/Background.jpg`

Comment: What happens if you replace `ImageSource="{Binding Settings.AppBackground}"` by a path to your image file: `ImageSource="C:\my\image.png"`? (Of course not as a solution, only to check if the issue is related to the binding or the use of the ImageBrush or whatever else.)

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint in the getter of the ImageSource property and checked what it's actually returning as part of the binding?

Comment: @Clemens Class Settings isn't in a different assembly and URI method doesn't work (can't locate the resource). I don't know why. That was the reason I had to use Stream. I know it's a patch, and I worry that I do not understand why it doesn't work... I also noticed that if I put the following code in xaml:
`ImageSource="/Application;component/Resources/Images/Background.jpg"`
The resource is loaded. But in the class Settings, the resource with same address doesn't loaded, even adding the prefix `pack://...`

Comment: @wkl `ImageSource="C\Background"` works. I am convinced that it is a problem in the search of the resource. Is it possible that there is a problem in resource loading because the UI loads in a different thread than where the Settings class is composed?

Comment: The Build Action is `Resource`, not `Embedded Resource` or anything else?

Comment: @Clemens I tested with the options `Resource`, `Embedded Resource` and `Content`. Doesn't work.

Comment: "Testing with options" doesn't make sense. It has to be Resource. Then rebuild the whole project.

Comment: I just checked with `Resource`. It doesn't work. I also just realized that inside the ViewModel `Uri` method doesn't work too. I cleaned the project, closed visual studio, opened visual studio, and re-compiled the project. It doesn't work. `/Application;component/Resources/Images/Backgro‌​und.jpg` address only works in xaml.